# Можно ли авторизоваться в vk через Intent без использования vk sdk?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, facebook-api

Для FaceBook сделали авторизацию через установленного клиента. Прям как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813815/android-facebook-api-single-sign-on)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth");
intent.putExtra("client_id", applicationId);
...
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, activityCode);
```

результат авторизации необходимо поймать методом

```
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Есть ли возможность аналогично авторизоваться в вКонтакте?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что такой способ для `Facebook` будет работать только ,если установлено приложение `Facebook`? А SDK представляет так же возможность авторизации в случае, когда приложение `Facebook` не установлено на телефоне. То же самое будет и с Вконтакте, если вы найдете способ сделать что-то подобное для него.

Comment: А вообще - `VK SDK` имеет открытый исходный код, высами можете посмотреть, как они это делают. https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk Например, я вот за пару минут нашел место, где стартует `Activity` для авторизации: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/VKServiceActivity.java строка 111

Comment: Если приложение не установлено, отправляем авторизоваться через WebView. Спасибо, пойду смотреть.

Comment: То есть, вы хотите сами изобрести свой собственный VK SDK и Facebook SDK?

Comment: Изобретать sdk желания нет ) Наш сотрудник сделал авторизацию на примере кодов vk sdk, как вы и писали выше.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, возможно только с vk SDK.

Comment: вы как бы не правы чуть более, чем на 100%